What is the inverse of "collapse all" in JetBrains IDEs?
I have accidentally collapsed my entire PHP class. I want to invert the action. I find only "collapse all"; I searched for "uncollapse", "unfold", yet this does not exist.
What is that inverse action called?

Just search for what you did, and what you want is right alongside it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding

@jonrsharpe I searched, and I didn't find that page. So what's the harm?

The wording is "Expand All":

You can also toggle this via shortcut:

Expand all: Ctrl + Shift + +
Collapse all: Ctrl + Shift + -

